# My Android YouTube App won't play certain codecs but plays others just fine

Tags: video, youtube, video-streaming

The Android YouTube app on my phone won't play any video with the vp09.00.51.08.01.01.01.01 codec, which seems to be every main stream, popular video.

My Android YouTube app will play videos with avc1.4d401e (134), which tend to be obscure low view videos. The only way I know how to check the codec is to look up the video from a desktop browser, right click the video and click "stats for nerds".

There are no errors shown in the app. The screen simply shows black and the audio plays normal.

YouTube works fine in the phone's browser, but not the app. I've uninstalled, reinstalled, cleared the cache, restarted the phone, and several combinations of all the above and can't get my YouTube app to work right.

Is there a way to update the codecs, or some other insight how to resolve the problem?

Edit:

The phone is a Korean model LG v20 F800L, so what Hax0 says makes perfect sense. I'm testing his answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention the device you are using. Your device does not seem to have license/support to play the VP9 codec in its HW codecs.

- One workaround is to tricking the YouTube app that you are using a different device which has license for VP9 codecs (Most recent devices does). Unfortunately you need to Root your device to achieve this because it required to modify System Build.prop file or use Xposed modules.
- Other option is to use third party or modded YouTube apps like Vanced Youtube which has option to Force VP9 codecs. Use google to download this.

Comment: I tried installing Vanced Youtube and it still does exactly the same thing. I think the codec is simply missing altogether. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Did you enable the "Force VP9 Codec" option from settings?

Answer (score -1):

Delete  the app then Go into settings and allow  unrecognised apps and it should work?